# i have a script in jquery ajax and do not work how to fix error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a jquery ajax code for validate username but not work:

> TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#username").change(function () {

        var user =$("#username").val().toString();
        $.ajax({

            url: "/home/userex",
            method: "get",
            data: { username1 : user }

        }).done(function (res) {

            if (res.data == true) {
                $("#uservalidate").val('نام کاربری قابل ثبت است');
            } else {
                $("#uservalidate").val("نام کاربری قبلا ثبت شده است");
            }


        });

    });
});


public JsonResult userex(string username1)
{
    var us = hackersRipository.find(username1);
    return Json(us,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: change method: "get", to method: "post", and try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same code and it worked successfully.

Can you please provide us with the detailed error from the browser console and the version of jQuery you are using.

Comment: Jquery version has 3.4.1

Comment: I suggest you disable all other java script files and libraries you are using except jQuery and test. It should work.

Then enable the libraries one by one and test each time until you find the file which causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to mention [HttpGet] in above the controller name and make sure jquery library working.